# php script to display directory listing results

Tags: php, directory

I'm working on making an affiliate directory and I'm having trouble finding a script to use.  I have done lots of searching everywhere here, google, bing, yahoo answers without the right results. I'm looking for a script to display results like these and in alphabetical order of results
http://www.jamaffiliates.com/directory/Business/Finance/
http://www.associateprograms.com/directory/books-and-art/clipart/

Comment: You could probably enhance your question by adding some information about your data model, what all template systems you might have tried or have read about and any other research you've already done (sans off-the-shelf solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you will need to provide more detail on this and future questions to really take advantage of Stack Overflow.  It is worth the time to invest in your own question!

That said, I assume you have an array or a database table with the affiliate info stored within.  Let's say you have an array like this:

```
$affiliates = array(
    1 = array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Affiliate 1',
        'info' => 'This is a good affiliate!'
    ),
    2 = array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Affiliate 2',
        'info' => 'This is also a really good affiliate!'
    )
);
```

You can then loop over this array like this:

`foreach($affiliates as $affiliate_id => $affiliate_detail) { ... }`

Within that code block, you may do something like `echo "<p>" . $affiliate_detail['info'] . "</p>";`.

If you want to sort alphabetically, the ideal way to do this is to implement a database table, like a MySQL table, which supports alphabetical sorting with a simple query like `select * from affiliates order by name`.  Something not nearly as scalable would be to use the affiliate names directly within the array provided above, instead of just the ID.  This way, you could use the PHP function `ksort($affiliates)` and like magic your array would be sorted alphabetically.  Actually, it would look at the array keys (the affiliate name, in this case), and re-order the array with them in alphabetical order.  To get the reverse, simply use `krsort($affiliates)`;